# While running ckan container, memory is increasing rapidly mainly because of `ckan_default` process

Tags: ckan

While I'm running Ckan container, memory is increasing rapidly mainly because of `ckan_default` process. Is there any way to limit the  memory for `ckan_default` process? If yes, where it should be defined or at which location that setting is present? 
Or how can I limit the memory?